# French-to-English translation of paper

Tags: algebraic-geometry, manifolds, characteristic-classes, translation-request, mathematical-french

I am currently reading a mathematical paper in French and I am not sure how to translate the following sentence:

> On suppose que la premiere classe de Chern $c_1(N)$ est $p\alpha$ ou $p$ est un entier plus grand que un et $\alpha$ une classe entiere non divisible;

Here is my best guess:

> Suppose the first Chern class $c_1(N)$ is $p\alpha$ where $p$ is an integer $>1$ and ... (?)

Any help would be great!

(Apologies for the missed out accents!)

Comment: What is the title/author of the paper, and in which section is this?

Comment: +1: Your guess is excellent: félicitations! (=congratulations !)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: The guess ends with (?) because (s)he doesn't know the translation of the last phrase about $\alpha$.

Comment: @rghthndsd The paper is by Berard Bergery, and the title is "Sur de novelles varietes Riemanniennes d'Einstein". It is in the introduction, paragraph 1.9.

Comment: @rghthn... [what have you got against vowels ?]: Oops, I thought the rest posed  no problem! Anyway, the rest  translates as "...and $\alpha$ a non divisible integral class;"

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: The gmail account with vowels was taken!

Comment: Dear consonantic friend: thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Also, I suggest you making your comment into an answer.

Comment: @rghthndsd: agreed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At  the request of @rghthndsd , I'll make my comment into an answer, albeit a community wiki one.
A possible translation is:

> Suppose the first Chern class $c_1(N)$ is $p\alpha$ where $p$ is an integer larger than one and   $\alpha$ a non divisible integral class;

Beware that for French authors "larger than one" might mean $\geq 1$.